Why a for-loop represents one more step than the statements in the loop body?

I do not understand why line 1 gets executed n times while line 2 and 3 gets executed n-1 times.
the (times) in this picture shows, how many times the algorithm gets executed.
I expected that every line gets executed at least n times. Because I don't understand the difference.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I agree that's a bit weird. One could argue that the first line is only executed once, if at all. None of this matters for determining the performance class of the algorithm, though.

Maybe whoever made that table looked at it from a compiler perspective, and decided that the for is executed one more time -- the last time is just to determine that the loop has finished.

Okay, thank you for this perspective. But overall I still do not understand the difference between n and n-1 in that example

The body of the loop (lines 2 and 3) is executed once for each value of i. How many values does i take on? Line 1 tells you. How many times does the loop condition need to be checked? Once for each time the body is executed, plus one more to find out you’re done.

Could you clarify where you got the image from? Book, chapter?

The reason why there is something about the first line that needs one more execution than the other two statements is that a loop condition needs to be evaluated to decide whether to continue or to stop. When the outcome is that the loop must stop, there is no more execution of the other statements, but the condition was still evaluated, so there is one more loop condition evaluation than there are iterations of the loop.
Maybe it helps to rewrite the pseudo code with a while loop:
i ← 1
while i <= n - 1:
    j ← random_integer_between(i, n)
    exchange A[i] with A[j]
    i ← i + 1

Now let's say that n = 3, then we get the following sequence of execution:
i ← 1
if i > n - 1 then stop   ' It's not true; continue
j ← random_integer_between(i, n)
exchange A[i] with A[j]
i ← i + 1                ' = 2
if i > n - 1 then stop   ' It's not true; continue
j ← random_integer_between(i, n)
exchange A[i] with A[j]
i ← i + 1                ' = 3
if i > n - 1 then stop   ' It's true, so stop

Now count how many times each statement is executed:
i ← 1                                  ' 1
while i <= n - 1:                      ' 3
    j ← random_integer_between(i, n)   ' 2
    exchange A[i] with A[j]            ' 2
    i ← i + 1                          ' 2

We see that there are 3 assignments to i (once i ← 1 and twice i ← i + 1), and 3 evaluations of the <= condition, so n. The other statements are executed 2 times, i.e. n-1 times.
I hope this clarifies why the for loop in your pseudocode represents n-1 iterations and n loop-condition evaluations.

It's worth noting that in many languages, the evaluation of a loop condition can be a lot more complicated than an increment and compare.  I think the language Knuth uses for his examples is much more restricted.
